# Динамическое изменение переменной в less стиле

Tags: css3, jquery, javascript, html5, less

Хай!
Изменяя переменную с less файле, помощью jquery, у меня появляется бага, конкретнее: все адреса что есть в файле style.less, типа background: url('../img/image.png'), после изменения переменной, становятся вида: background: url(image.png). Вот и вся проблема) Кто то сталкивался или может догадывается, что не так? Так же и со шрифтами. Они вообще в другой папке. Спасибо.
ссылка на код и дерево: 
i .piccy .info/i9/39d811a09ce2550cfb7b1243d9efcbdf/1403942643/323395/746883/Bezymiannyi.jpg

Comment: Вот так я меняю переменную: less.modifyVars({'@color': value});

Comment: Этот баг пофиксили с версии less.1.4.js